syscall: 'rename' error while install json server by using npm install -g json-server command
I am trying to install json-server by using npm install -g json-server command on Mac but am getting the following error:
(node:34559) ExperimentalWarning: CommonJS module /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/debug/src/node.js is loading ES Module /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/supports-color/index.js using require().
Support for loading ES Module in require() is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm error code EACCES
npm error syscall rename
npm error path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server
npm error dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.json-server-SmlbN4FS
npm error errno -13
npm error Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server' -\'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.json-server-SmlbN4FS'
npm error     at async Object.rename (node:internal/fs/promises:784:10)
npm error     at async moveFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/fs/lib/move-file.js:30:5)
npm error     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm error     at async \[reifyPackages\] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:325:11)
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:142:5)
npm error     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:150:5)
npm error     at async Npm.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:207:9)
npm error     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5) {
npm error   errno: -13,
npm error   code: 'EACCES',
npm error   syscall: 'rename',
npm error   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server',
npm error   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.json-server-SmlbN4FS'
npm error }
npm error
npm error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm error It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm error
npm error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm error the command again as root/Administrator.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/fllap0630_mayurpatil/.npm/\_logs/2024-12-05T17_07_36_861Z-debug-0.log


global install typically needs admin permissions on unix-like systems

This question is similar to: npm, global install failing, getting Error: EACCES: permission denied. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this command: sudo npm install -g json-server instead of npm install -g json-server
I hope it helps!

Tried sudo npm install -g json-server but getting following error now
14 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
